# how to get the product after the colons

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

so im learning this program BMI calculator, and i want the answers to be written after the ':', not under it. can anyone help me pls? is it even possible to get that type of answer?

heres the code:

```
name = "hello"
height_m = 2
weight_kg = 110

bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
print("bmi:")
print(bmi)
if bmi < 25:
    print(name)
    print("is not overweight")
else:
    print(name)
    print("is overweight")

#printed:
bmi:
27.5
hello
is overweight

#but what i want is this:
bmi: 27.5
hello is overweight
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a comma in the same `print` statement instead of two separate ones.

```
print("bmi:",bmi)
```

instead of

```
print("bmi:")
print(bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
name = "hello"
height_m = 2
weight_kg = 110

bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
print("bmi: {}".format(bmi)
if bmi < 25:
    print("{} is not overweight".format(name))
else:
    print("{} is overweight".format(name))

#prints:
bmi: 27.5
hello is overweight
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
name = "hello"
height_m = 2
weight_kg = 110

bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
print("bmi:", end=' ')
print(bmi)
if bmi < 25:
    print(name, end=' ')
    print("is not overweight")
else:
    print(name, end=' ')
    print("is overweight")
```

Or you can put everything in a single print statement like this,

```
print(name, "is overweight")
print("bmi:", bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
print("bmi:", bmi) # the simplest
```

or

```
print(f"bmi: {bmi}") # f string in Python 3
```

or

```
print("bmi: ", end="") # Your original code, modified
print(bmi)
```

or

```
print("bmi: %s " % bmi) # too extreme -- don't do it for this simple case
```

or

```
print("bmi: {}".format(bmi)) # too extreme
```